# prisma overide it's own scheme

Tags: prisma

I got a prisma scheme like this

```sql
created            DateTime? @default(now())
updated            DateTime? @default(dbgenerated("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)"))
```

I decide to push this to the database, I do the command "npx prisma db push". after that, upon viewing the data struction in the UI client, it showed exactly what I want my data structure to be, which is like this

[image]

Now, I'm gonna do a "npx prisma db pull". What happen gonna be weird. My schema is now updated to this

```sql
created   DateTime? @default(now())
  updated   DateTime? @default(now())
```

It changed my shcema. Now if I do "npx prisma db push" the data structure will be nothing like what I want originally.

So why does prisma change it own schema ?